# Django: how to pass color as context variable to templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I need some help:

I want my view to pass as context parameter a color to the template in order to overrule the default colors within the svg files displayed by the page.

I have a list of color constants:

```
COLORS = {"W": "#ffffff", "V": "#065636", "B": "#0253A5", "R": "#CC1011"}
```

I have within my view definition the definition of context variables:

```
view_context = {
    'user_display_name': user.user_display,
    'lightcolor': COLORS[user.lightcolor],
}
return render(request, 'pages/page5.html', context=view_context)
```

and within my template (pages/page5.html), I have a `<style>` section where to define the CSS styles:

```
<style>
    .X {
        /* fill: #065636 !IMPORTANT; */
        fill: "{{ lightcolor }}" !IMPORTANT;
    }
</style>
```

`.X {fill: #065636 !IMPORTANT;}` works just fine

while `.X {fill: "{{ lightcolor }}" !IMPORTANT;}`

does not work and is ignored, I guess because lightcolor is a string `"#065636"` instead of a RGBcolor `#065636`

similarly `.X {fill: {{ lightcolor }} !IMPORTANT;}` does not even appear to be a recognized syntax

and I cannot find anything relevant on internet

How could I pass the color as context parameter into the `<style>` section of the template and get this working?

Comment: The `fill` property is for [setting the color of an SVG shape](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/fill.html). Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes it is - as I said, using the color coding directly, the code is executed as I want. issue comes when replacing the color coding by the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the origin of the problem ! I'm working on VS-code on a PC.
When I save, the formating of my html file changes from:

```
.Y {
        fill: {{darkcolor}} !IMPORTANT;
    }
```

into:

```
    .Y {
        fill: {
                {
                darkcolor
            }
        }

         !IMPORTANT;
    }
```

Braces after the fill are also marked red to indicate that there is an issue with my syntax (before and after saving and code reorganization)

If I manage to modify my file outside of VS-code ... all is good and everything is working as it should !

Could anyone explain me how I could avoid to have this part of code reorganized?
(is it because of my linter, or because of something else? stoping linting did not appear to change anything)

Comment: OK. I tried few other things ... 
and finally succeeded having my code disorganized and the instruction 
fill: {{darkcolor}} !IMPORTANT;
put on several lines.
I installed the in VScode the Django extension  (batisteo.vscode-django) that formats correctly the html code to include Django template notations

Answer (score 0):

try using inline styling.

For example

```
<h4 style="color:{{ color }}">Records</h4>
```

Comment: as I'm trying to over-ride coloring within a SVG file, this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The `fill` property is [for setting the color of an SVG shape](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/fill.html). Assuming that's what you're trying to do, your syntax should work.

Working Demo: https://repl.it/@JoshG5/Django-Template

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
  COLORS = {"W": "#ffffff", "V": "#065636", "B": "#0253A5", "R": "#CC1011"}
  view_context = {
    'user_display_name': "foo",
    'lightcolor': COLORS["V"],
  }
  return render(request, 'page.html', context=view_context)
```

**templates/page.html**

```
<style>
    .X {
        /* fill: #065636 !IMPORTANT; */
        fill: {{ lightcolor }} !IMPORTANT;
    }
</style>
<svg height="250px" width="600px" class="X"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      version="1.1"> 
      <circle class="opacity1" cx="100"
        cy="100" r="50" /> 
      <circle class="opacity2" cx="250"
        cy="100" r="50" /> 
      <circle class="opacity3" cx="400"
        cy="100" r="50" /> 
      <circle class="opacity4" cx="550"
        cy="100" r="50" /> 
</svg>
```

You should see the circles rendered with the desired color.

If instead, you are trying to fill a block or inline element, try using the `color` property:

```
.X {
    color: {{ lightcolor }} !important;
}
```

Comment: The goal is to re-color svg shapes. So fill is the way to go. In addition, it does work with .X {  color: #065636 !important;} . The main problem I have is that contrary to what happens in your working demo, on my computer, neither .X {  color: {{ lightcolor }} !important;} nor .X {  color: "{{ lightcolor }}" !important;} is working. The result is the same as .X {  color: "#065636" !important;} : no recoloring

Comment: would you know by chance how I could transform "#065636" into the corresponding #065636 RGBcolor object ?

Comment: OK, I found the origin of the problem ! I'm working on VS-code on a PC. when I save, the formating change from .Y {
            fill: {{darkcolor}} !IMPORTANT;
        }